# Why does the total from last row is not calculating the sum?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a project that involves making an estimate and adding up does results. I am using the method GET and using some of the the info from the url. Also i am using WordPress to build the Web Page. Problem is that sum of the TOTAL column is not working and showing in the TOTAL row that i made. Is not an error but i think I need to add one more piece of code or change something in the javascript. So why does the id:"total" not showing the sum of the whole column? is the total.value wrong? does the id:"system_total" have a problem?

Here is how the HTML looks like:

```
 <form >
<h2>Cotizacion</h2>
<table class="Cotization">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:25%;font-size:16px;text-align:center;">Description</th>
      <th style="width:15%;" class="qtyhd" title="qtytt">Qty</th>
      <th style="width:15%;" class="ratehd" title="ratett">Rate</th>
      <th style="width:15%;" class="tlhd" title="totaltt">Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PV Grid Tied System</td>
      <td> <input id="system_qty" name="system_qty" value="1" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="system_rate" name="system_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="system_total">  </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Solar Modules 250w</td>
      <td> <input id="modules_qty" name="modules_qty" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="modules_rate" name="modules_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="modules_total">  </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Inverter</td>
      <td> <input id="inverter_qty" name="inverter_qty" value="1" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="inverter_rate" name="inverter_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="inverter_total"> </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aluminum Fames</td>
      <td> <input id="aluminum_qty" name="aluminum_qty" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="aluminum_rate" name="aluminum_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="aluminum_total">  </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Service Disconnect</td>
      <td> <input id="servicedt_qty" name="servicedt_qty" value="1" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="servicedt_rate" name="servicedt_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="servicedt_total"> </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Installation</td>
      <td> <input id="installation_qty" name="installation_qty" value="1" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="installation_rate" name="installation_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="installation_total">  </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Down Payment</td>
      <td> <input id="dnpayment_qty" name="dnpayment_qty" value="-1" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="dnpayment_rate" name="dnpayment_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="dnpayment_total">  </output></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> <input id="total" name="total"/></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

And here is the javascript that might have the problem:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var system_size = Number(getParameterByName('system_size'));
  var system_rate_input = document.getElementById('system_rate');
    var modules_qty = document.getElementById('modules_qty');
  var aluminum_qty = document.getElementById('aluminum_qty');
  var systemTotal = Number(document.getElementById('system_total').innerText);
  var moduleTotal = Number(document.getElementById('modules_total').innerText);
  var inverterTotal = Number(document.getElementById('inverter_total').innerText);
  var aluminumTotal = Number(document.getElementById('aluminum_total').innerText);
  var servicedtTotal = Number(document.getElementById('servicedt_total').innerText);
  var installationTotal = Number(document.getElementById('installation_total').innerText);
  var dnpaymentTotal = Number(document.getElementById('dnpayment_total').innerText);
  var total = document.getElementById('total');
  modules_qty.value = Number(system_size) * 4;
  aluminum_qty.value = Number(modules_qty.value);
  system_rate_input.value = 2.9 * 1000 * 1.2 * system_size;
  updateSystemTotal()
  updateModulesTotal()
  updateInverterTotal()
  updateAluminumTotal()
  updateServiceTotal()
  updateInstallationTotal()
  updateDownPaymentTotal()
  total.value = Number(systemTotal) + Number(moduleTotal) + Number(inverterTotal) + Number(aluminumTotal) + Number(servicedtTotal) + Number(installationTotal) + Number(dnpaymentTotal);
})

// FIRST ROW

function updateSystemTotal() {
    var output = document.getElementById('system_total');
  var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('system_qty').value);
  var system_rate = Number(document.getElementById('system_rate').value);
  output.innerText = quantity * system_rate;
}

document.getElementById('system_rate').addEventListener('change', updateSystemTotal)

document.getElementById('system_qty').addEventListener('change', updateSystemTotal)

// Second ROW

function updateModulesTotal() {
    var output = document.getElementById('modules_total');
  var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('modules_qty').value);
  var modules_rate = Number(document.getElementById('modules_rate').value);
  output.innerText = quantity * modules_rate;
}

document.getElementById('modules_rate').addEventListener('change', updateModulesTotal)

document.getElementById('modules_qty').addEventListener('change', updateModulesTotal)

// Third ROW

function updateInverterTotal() {
    var output = document.getElementById('inverter_total');
  var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('inverter_qty').value);
  var inverter_rate = Number(document.getElementById('inverter_rate').value);
  output.innerText = quantity * inverter_rate;
}

document.getElementById('inverter_rate').addEventListener('change', updateInverterTotal)

document.getElementById('inverter_qty').addEventListener('change', updateInverterTotal)

// Fourth ROW

function updateAluminumTotal() {
    var output = document.getElementById('aluminum_total');
  var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('aluminum_qty').value);
  var aluminum_rate = Number(document.getElementById('aluminum_rate').value);
  output.innerText = quantity * aluminum_rate;
}

document.getElementById('aluminum_rate').addEventListener('change', updateAluminumTotal)

document.getElementById('aluminum_qty').addEventListener('change', updateAluminumTotal)

// Fith ROW

function updateServiceTotal() {
    var output = document.getElementById('servicedt_total');
  var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('servicedt_qty').value);
  var servicedt_rate = Number(document.getElementById('servicedt_rate').value);
  output.innerText = quantity * servicedt_rate;
}
document.getElementById('servicedt_rate').addEventListener('change', updateServiceTotal)

document.getElementById('servicedt_qty').addEventListener('change', updateServiceTotal)
// Six ROW

function updateInstallationTotal() {
    var output = document.getElementById('installation_total');
  var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('installation_qty').value);
  var installation_rate = Number(document.getElementById('installation_rate').value);
  output.innerText = quantity * installation_rate;
}
document.getElementById('installation_rate').addEventListener('change', updateInstallationTotal)

document.getElementById('installation_qty').addEventListener('change', updateInstallationTotal)

//Seventh ROW

function updateDownPaymentTotal() {
    var output = document.getElementById('dnpayment_total');
  var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('dnpayment_qty').value);
  var dnpayment_rate = Number(document.getElementById('dnpayment_rate').value);
  output.innerText = quantity * dtpayment_rate;
}
document.getElementById('dnpayment_rate').addEventListener('change', updateDownPaymentTotal)

document.getElementById('dnpayment_qty').addEventListener('change', updateDownPaymentTotal)

// DON't TOUCH ANYTHING BELOW THIS POINT!!!

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
</script>
```

Comment: any error that you see in console?

Comment: No error on the console is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var systemTotal = Number(document.getElementById('system').innerText);
```

There is no element called "system" in the snippets you provided. Are you sure you don't need to get the value from "system_total"?

---

**Edit:**

Total is showing 0 at the beginning, because the subtotals aren't initialized. To fix this, you can use your update functions before calculating the total.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var system_size = Number(getParameterByName('system_size'));
    var system_rate_input = document.getElementById('system_rate');
    var modules_qty = document.getElementById('modules_qty');
    var aluminum_qty = document.getElementById('aluminum_qty');
    var total = document.getElementById('total');
    modules_qty.value = Number(system_size) * 4;
    aluminum_qty.value = Number(modules_qty.value);
    system_rate_input.value = 2.9 * 1000 * 1.2 * system_size;
    updateSystemTotal();
    updateModulesTotal();
    updateInverterTotal();
    updateAluminumTotal();
    updateServiceTotal();
    updateInstallationTotal();
    updateDownPaymentTotal();
    updateTotal();
})

function updateTotal() {
    var total = document.getElementById('total');
    var systemTotal = Number(document.getElementById('system_total').innerText);
    var moduleTotal = Number(document.getElementById('modules_total').innerText);
    var inverterTotal = Number(document.getElementById('inverter_total').innerText);
    var aluminumTotal = Number(document.getElementById('aluminum_total').innerText);
    var servicedtTotal = Number(document.getElementById('servicedt_total').innerText);
    var installationTotal = Number(document.getElementById('installation_total').innerText);
    var dnpaymentTotal = Number(document.getElementById('dnpayment_total').innerText);
    total.value = Number(systemTotal) + Number(moduleTotal) + Number(inverterTotal) + Number(aluminumTotal) + Number(servicedtTotal) + Number(installationTotal) + Number(dnpaymentTotal);
}
```

Further, you are updating the subtotals as soon as the user edits Quantities or Rates, but you are not updating the "Total" value.
You could call `updateTotal()` in your own update functions to solve this issue:

```
function updateSystemTotal() {
    var output = document.getElementById('system_total');
  var quantity = Number(document.getElementById('system_qty').value);
  var system_rate = Number(document.getElementById('system_rate').value);
  output.innerText = quantity * system_rate;
  updateTotal();
}
```

Comment: Is this a comment or answer?

Comment: As far as the blue box is telling me, I "must have 50 reputation to comment". I could change the "Are you sure " - part to "Change it to "system_total", however I can not exclude, that there is any other "system" element, that Kenneth is trying to access.

Comment: He is right, there was an error on the id of var systemTotal, the id "system" is changed to "system_total".  That was a change i made last night, sorry for the inconvenience. But the problem is still there, i still get  0 as a result.

Comment: Are you filling your totals with values?
document.getElementById('system_total').innerText; seems to be empty

Comment: There is still more code for the javascript, like output id="system_total" has  an function that multiplies system_qty with system_rate and then the out put goes to system_total. Would you like me to show the full javscript code?

Comment: @Lelefant I updated the full code, so you can get a better glimpse and more understanding of what is happening.

Comment: It seems like you are only updating the subtotals when a value is changed. In the first function should update all the other totals one, before the total is calculated for the first time.
You should also update total each time any other value (or subtotal) is changed.

Comment: Great job @Lelefant you solve the problem. But now if someone makes an input on dnpayment_rate and the dnpayment_total changes or system_rate is change and system_total changes, how do I maintain updated the "total". Because the "total" is not changing when someone makes an input on does cells. Note: the dnpayment_total will always be negative, so it subtracts the "total"

Comment: did you add the last line in my second code snippet? You have to copy it in every "update...Total" method that you created.

Comment: Oh sorry was not aware of that @Lelefant, Thank you for everything. I wish i could give you 2 votes xD

Answer (score 0):

Copy my code and Run it :

javascript(1.js) :

```js
function rr() {
                 var system_size = document.getElementById('system_qty').value;
                 var system_rate_input = document.getElementById('system_rate').value;
                 var modules_qty = document.getElementById('modules_qty').value;
                 var modules_rate = document.getElementById('modules_rate').value;
                 var inverter_qty = document.getElementById('inverter_qty').value;
                 var inverter_rate = document.getElementById('inverter_rate').value;
                 var aluminum_qty = document.getElementById('aluminum_qty').value;
                 var aluminum_rate = document.getElementById('aluminum_rate').value;
                 var servicedt_qty = document.getElementById('servicedt_qty').value;
                 var servicedt_rate = document.getElementById('servicedt_rate').value;
                 var installation_qty = document.getElementById('installation_qty').value;
                 var installation_rate = document.getElementById('installation_rate').value;
                 var dnpayment_qty = document.getElementById('dnpayment_qty').value;
                 var dnpayment_rate = document.getElementById('dnpayment_rate').value;
                
                  var systemTotal = system_size * system_rate_input;
                  document.getElementById('system_total').innerHTML = systemTotal;
                  var moduleTotal = modules_rate  * modules_qty;
                  document.getElementById('modules_total').innerHTML = moduleTotal;
                  var inverterTotal = inverter_qty * inverter_rate;
                  document.getElementById('inverter_total').innerHTML = inverterTotal;
                  var aluminumTotal =aluminum_qty * aluminum_rate;
                   document.getElementById('aluminum_total').innerHTML = aluminumTotal;
                  var servicedtTotal = servicedt_qty * servicedt_rate;
                  document.getElementById('servicedt_total').innerHTML = servicedtTotal;
                  var installationTotal = installation_qty * installation_rate;
                  document.getElementById('installation_total').innerHTML = installationTotal;
                  var dnpaymentTotal = dnpayment_qty * dnpayment_rate;
                   document.getElementById('dnpayment_total').innerHTML = dnpaymentTotal;
                  var Total = document.getElementById('total');
                  aluminum_qty = system_size * 4;
                  system_rate_input = 2.9 * 1000 * 1.2 * system_size;
                  Total.value = systemTotal + moduleTotal + inverterTotal+ aluminumTotal + servicedtTotal+ installationTotal + dnpaymentTotal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
    
    <body>
        <script src="1.js"></script>
        <form name="frm" >
<h2>Cotizacion</h2>
<table class="Cotization">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:25%;font-size:16px;text-align:center;">Description</th>
      <th style="width:15%;" class="qtyhd" title="qtytt">Qty</th>
      <th style="width:15%;" class="ratehd" title="ratett">Rate</th>
      <th style="width:15%;" class="tlhd" title="totaltt">Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>PV Grid Tied System</td>
      <td> <input id="system_qty" name="system_qty" value="1" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="system_rate" name="system_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="system_total"> </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Solar Modules 250w</td>
      <td> <input id="modules_qty" name="modules_qty" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="modules_rate" name="modules_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="modules_total">  </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Inverter</td>
      <td> <input id="inverter_qty" name="inverter_qty" value="1" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="inverter_rate" name="inverter_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="inverter_total"> </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aluminum Fames</td>
      <td> <input id="aluminum_qty" name="aluminum_qty" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="aluminum_rate" name="aluminum_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="aluminum_total">  </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Service Disconnect</td>
      <td> <input id="servicedt_qty" name="servicedt_qty" value="1" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="servicedt_rate" name="servicedt_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="servicedt_total"> </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Installation</td>
      <td> <input id="installation_qty" name="installation_qty" value="1" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="installation_rate" name="installation_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="installation_total">  </output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Down Payment</td>
      <td> <input id="dnpayment_qty" name="dnpayment_qty" value="-1" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <input id="dnpayment_rate" name="dnpayment_rate" value="0" type="number" /></td>
      <td> <output id="dnpayment_total">  </output></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> <input value="" id="total" name="total"/></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
        <button id="btn" onclick="rr()">Click</button>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Nice job but the console gave me a syntax error on javascript, i wonder what it is? :l Btw: i forgot to tell you im using Wordpress